# delphi indy скачать файл с сервера не с самого начала

Tags: delphi, indy

Как скачать файл если часть файла уже было скачано и нужно скачать не с самого начала файл а с того места где был обрыв,
Когда происходит разрыв интернета или какая то ошибка сети

```
var G:TamHttp;
    MS:TMemoryStream;
begin
    G:= TamHttp.Create;
    G.Http.OnWork:= HTTPWork;
    G.Http.OnWorkBegin:= HTTPWorkBegin;
    G.Http.OnWorkEnd:= HTTPWorkEnd;

    MS:= TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      G.Http.Get(url,MS);
      G.Http.Disconnect;
      MS.SaveToFile(patch);
    finally
      MS.Free;
      G.Free;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Если сервер поддерживает range запросы [HTTP range requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests), то просто указываете в HTTP заголовках нужное смещение [Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Range) и получаете желаемое.

Comment: Что такое `TamHttp` и при чём тут Indy?

Answer (score 1):

вопрос разобран тут
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963246/download-pause-and-resume-an-download-using-indy-components

вкратце:

```
if aRangeEnd < fLength then
  Http.Request.Range := IntToStr(fFileStream.Position) + '-' +  IntToStr(aRangeEnd)
else
  Http.Request.Range := IntToStr(fFileStream.Position) + '-';

Http.Get(Url, fFileStream);
```